# Create road section using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, react-konva, konva

In my React application I want to create not the usual `form` for creating road section.

For example, I have this scheme in png format.

[image]

But I want to create an interactive editor in which it will be possible to create schemes, save them to the server and then reuse.

I will try to simulate a situation

User want to create a new road section.
Road has  six lanes. (image above)

1. It should be possible for the user to draw this diagram himself (all lines, circles, images etc.)
2. Save this data to server

Then user want to recive data about one special lane. (this functionality taken out in another component)

So, user open new component, where he can get statistic by some lane(s) which he will choose

1. Get saved scheme from the server
2. Render this scheme and integrate checkbox for each lane

After a lane has been selected, user sends information to the server, on which lane it wants to receive a summary (statistics)

I find Konva framework https://konvajs.org/ or p5.js (https://p5js.org/), but it seems to me that this approach is very cumbersome

What can i use for build something like that?

Comment: I think this question is too broad in scope.

Comment: do you want to build an image editor, do change the png you mentioned?
or should your program work on a vector representation and let you draw new lines and move existing lines around?
or should your program understand something of roads - maybe to be able to simulate them later on?

Comment: My program should  work on a vector representation  and let me draw new shapes and after I created a road I want to integrate some checkboxes in this component, 
for example,receive a response from the server only by recordings from a particular selected band

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many canvas frameworks that can do that job.

- https://konvajs.org/
- http://fabricjs.com/
- https://www.createjs.com/easeljs
- https://two.js.org/
- and many others

Or you can just draw directly into DOM with SVG.